# Login with curl returns the same login page

Tags: php, curl

I'm making a script to test a web application.
So first I want the script to log in, so I made this code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/ASTechOLE/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for($i = 0; $i < $tags->length; $i++){
    $grab = $tags->item($i);
    if($grab->getAttribute('name') === 'csrf_token'){
        $token = $grab->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
$data = array(
    "username"=>"008C108",
    "password"=>"8706405",
    //"form"=>"submit"
    //"csrf_token"=>$token,
    //"submitLogin"=>"submitLogin"
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/ASTechOLE/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;


?>
```

But when I run it, I just get the login page. I don't get any error but it doesnt do anything.
Why could this be?

The form action goes to login-submit.php, so that's something I changed in my code. Now I get `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in D:\Programas\xampp\htdocs\CURL\curl.php on line 10`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `login.php` actually do the login or does that forward to another page that does the processing?

Comment: We'd really need to see the login.php code to give any sort of answer.

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not really sure right now but I can check it.

Comment: Oh I just checked it, the form action goes to login-submit.php. I will edit the question to add it

Comment: Why are you doing that DOMDocument stuff if you're not actually using the data you get from it?  Also, if the form submits to login-submit.php, then you need to change the url used by your second curl block.

Comment: @PatrickQ To get the csrf_token, but I commented it since I didnt use it. Now I just get a blank page

Comment: Why aren't you using it (the token) though?  Either it is needed or it isn't.  If it is, you should be using it.  If it isn't, remove the DOMDocument stuff.

Comment: I'm kind of new to all of this. I checked the request header and realized it doesnt require any token so I commented that

Comment: It feels unlikely that csrf_token is not required by the server but without that code it's hard to tell. Have you used the browser's web inspector to analyse the POST request, and matched your $data array to what the browser sends?